# Setminus strange behaviour

Tags: symbols

I want to write: the set of real numbers minus set {0, 1}.

This is how I try:

```
\mathbb{R} \setminus\{0,1\}
```

And the outcome is in the picture...

[image]

It seems `\mathbb{R}$ $\setminus\{0,1\}$` solves the issue but there is one space I do not want.

So... `\mathbb{R}\!$ $\!\setminus\{0,1\}$`solves it all... But that is strange.

I think that is the minimal example:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,oldlfont,graphics,oldgerm,latexsym,dsfont,fge}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage {pstricks,pst-node,pst-coil}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\textheight = 19cm
\textwidth = 13.5cm
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0, 1\}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should post a minimal compilable example so we can reproduce the problem. Most of the time you will find the solution by yourself while narrowing down the code to get such minimal compilable example.

Comment: Ok. `$\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0, 1 \}$` does not produce the wanted output. But this part: `$\setminus \{ 0, 1 \}$` is ok... I mean what I see is {0, 1}. It seems that the mathbb changes the output somehow.

Comment: We need to somehow reproduce the output you receive. How can we achieve that? Do you receive any weird errors/warnings in your `.log`?

Comment: Instead of trying to find silly work arounds you should better spent the time and make a complete minimal example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `oldlfont` package that you are loading is the cause of the mishap.

It's a package that is distributed only for ensuring compatibility of old document written for LaTeX 2.09 (that is more than twenty years ago).

Don't load it.

Comment: I was just about to say that:-)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! How did you notice that?

Comment: @user79879 Avoid loading scores of packages just because you loaded them in some document or somebody passed you some template. Load a package only if you need it.

Answer (score 6):

Your input is not as you show, you have a misplaced `}` leaving `0` and `1` in the scope of `\mathbb`.

The following produces the posted image.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{R \setminus\{0,1\}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I haven't. It does not change whether I leave the numbers in the scope of \mathbb.

Comment: @user79879 `0` and `1` in the font used by `\mathbb` produce exactly the `\models` characters that you show. If you think that the 0 is not in the scope of `\mathbb` do as I did here produce a _complete_  small document that reproduces the effect. You can run this example, i can not run your fragment.